# About probability density function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a question about probability density function in my book.
It reads:

> A Probability density function is of the form $p(x) = Ke^{-a|x|}$ , $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$.The value of $K$ is:

- 1] 0.5
- 2] 1
- 3] $0.5a$
- 4] $a$

I think it should be `2] 1` because when $p(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ , then $p(x)$ is equal to $1$ , but in my book it says the answer to be `3]`$0.5a$.

Could someone please explain how this happens.

Thanks a lot.

### Edit:

Ok , I got my answer. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: $p(x)$ is a density, not a probability or an integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume $a>0$.  (Otherwise, this DEFINITELY is not a density function.)

As you note, you need the integral of the density on $(-\infty,\infty)$ to be $1$. So:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Ke^{-a\lvert x\rvert}\,dx=2K\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax}\,dx=2K\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^Te^{-ax}\,dx=2K\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\left(-\frac{e^{-at}}{a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)=\frac{2K}{a}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
1 = \int_\mathbb{R}Ke^{-a|x|}dx = 2K\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}dx = \frac{2K}{a}
$$